# SELECT WHERE IN() AND NOT IN()

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables

```
Articles        Channels        ArticlesChannels
pk    id        pk    id        pk    articlePk    channelPk
1     a1        1     c1        1     1            1
2     a2        2     c2        2     1            2
                                3     2            2
```

Now I want to select all Articles that are included in one collection AND excluded in another.

**Ex:** Select all articles that have Channel a1 AND not Channel a2.
**Correct result:** Empty since both articles are in Channel c2.

**Ex:** Select all articles that have Channel a1.
**Correct result:** Article1 only one in Channel c1.

My SQL looks like this:

```
SELECT a.id 
FROM articles a, channels c, articlechannels ac 
WHERE a.pk=ac.articlePk 
AND ac.channelPk = c.pk 
AND c.id IN ('a1') 
AND c.id NOT IN ('a2');
```

The problem is that the result doesn't exclude result that are existing in the c.id NOT IN ('a2').

Any ideas?

Comment: do you mean `Select all articles that have Channel c1 AND not Channel c2.` ?

Comment: This sounds a lot like homework

Comment: I highly doubt you can achieve what you want using a single query, i see what you want to do , and you have to loop through your channels checking each time if all the articles exists for other channels (assuming that the number of articles and channels are bigger than your example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query looks just fine except for typos.

The problem is it doesn't fit for this requirement:

> Ex: Select all articles that have Channel a1 AND not Channel a2.
>   Correct result: Empty since both articles are in Channel c2.

Looks like you want Set1 minus Set2 operation which is not supported by MySQL.

But you can workaround it using something like this:

```
select a.id, sum(case when c.id = 'c1' then 1 else 0 end) as c1, sum(case when c.id = 'c2' then 1 else 0 end) as c2
from Articles a
inner join ArticleChannels ac
on a.pk = ac.articlePk
inner join Channels c
on c.pk = ac.channelPk
group by a.id
having c1 = 1 and c2 = 0;
```

Here is [SQL Fiddle for the case](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8dee5/20)

UPDATED:
You can also go on with subquery:

```
SELECT a.id 
FROM articles a, channels c, articlechannels ac 
WHERE a.pk=ac.articlePk 
AND ac.channelPk = c.pk 
AND c.id IN ('a1') 
AND a.id NOT IN (
  SELECT a.id 
  FROM articles a, channels c, articlechannels ac 
  WHERE a.pk=ac.articlePk 
  AND ac.channelPk = c.pk 
  AND c.id NOT IN ('a2')
)
```

Comment: The first option worked perfectly in a small test scenario. How about the scalability of this query in a scenario with 100K articles and 1K channels (ca 1-5 channels / article)? How about performance of the first solution in respect to the second one?

Comment: @Niclas: Strictly speaking, getting the results in an efficient way is a different problem from the one of getting the correct results, because it begs more information, like what execution plan is produced for the present solution, what indices you've got, possibly something else. If the performance is really that bad, you might want to consider posting a new question or at least leaving this one open (and perhaps introducing a bounty later on if it ceases getting enough attention).